# logback.xml from dependency overwrites my own logback.xml

Tags: java, spring, logging, logback, slf4j

I am using a spring boot application, and i have logback.xml
which after build I store outside the jar.
In application.yml I declare the path to my logback:

```
logging:
  config: logback.xml
```

I add dependency which has its own logback.xml.Now when i start my app with command

```
java  -Dspring.profiles.active=local -Dspring.config.location=configLocation -jar ./my-app.jar
```

i see in log:

```
18:10:51,480 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
18:10:51,481 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
18:10:51,482 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/C:/projects/RegistryBack/registry-app/target/itr-registry-distribution/itr-registry.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/mq-logback-appender-2.1.jar!/logback.xml]
```

My logback is not used, but is taken from the library:/BOOT-INF/lib/mq-logback-appender-2.1.jar!/logback.xml.

I could force my logback.xml to be used with commands used only together:

```
-Dlogging.config=./logback.xml -Dlogback.configurationFile=./logback.xml
```

but this is strange and seems very bad.

Comment: can you update your question with what help you are looking for?

Comment: point logging config to `file:./logback.xml` and it should work